# Making a biased agressive enemy in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My goal is to have a scene with multiple randomly generated enemies shooting projectiles at each other that randomly assigned teams when they choose. I am able to get them to shoot enemies of a tag if put to target a tag. but unable to get enemies to not shoot at themselves and their own team when randomly generated. This is obviously because I set it to shoot all objects of the same tag and set itself to that tag since it's all initiated by one object, but that's the problem. I don't know how to get them to target all but themselves.

I am fairly new to unity and C# and might be confusing, so to further explain, each object is initiated of a single prefab with an ai, and projectile script. But as each object or entity is initiated, it has nothing to reference or to shoot because I don't know how to reference all objects but itself when moving, and the same for the bullet that it's shooting.

The bullet is shot and is put a child under the object,

so I need 2 things;

- how to reference all objects but the self of or not of a team besides terrain,
- how to reference the parent of a bullet so the bullet doesn't target what shot it.

current crappy wishful code for the bullet targeting system:

```
  void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (gameObject.transform.tag is not PARENT)
        {
            target_object = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("All but parent Entity");
        }

        if (target_object)
        {
            Vector3 direction = target_object.transform.position - transform.position;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x, direction.y).normalized * force;

            float rot = Mathf.Atan2(-direction.y, -direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rot);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do, but the use of `FindGameObjectWithTag` is weird because it means enemies won't their target at random, they will shoot whichever target `FindGameObjectWithTag` returns deterministically. I suggest writing your own algorithm to iterate over all targets with the tag and choose one at random, and then you'll be able to also add a condition that `target_object != this.gameObject`

Comment: There's not much to go off of here, but a couple of thoughts if you really want to use this approach: initialize your bullet by passing it the parent object before firing it, and use FindGameObjectsWithTag (the plural version) to get all possible matches. Then you can ignore the parent gameobject and select a target based on some criteria (e.g. Closest enemy, lowest health, etc). If you include the code that fires the bullet, there might be enough information to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If all your enemies have the same script you can always do something like

```
public enum Team {TeamOne, TeamTwo}
public Team team;

void Start()
{
    if (gameObject.transform.tag is not PARENT)
    {
        // find all enemy types in the scene
        var allEnemies = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Enemy>(); 
        
        // exclude all enemies that are on our team
        var enemiesNotOnTeam = allEnemies.Where(enemy => enemy.team != team).ToArray();
 
        // pick a random remaining enemy
        target_object = enemiesNotOnTeam[Random.Range(0, enemiesNotOnTeam.Length - 1)].gameObject;
    }

...
}
```

Tags are not really very useful here as you alreay have a way of knowing which game objects are enemies - its the gameobjects with the enemy script attached!

Comment: For "var enemiesNotOnTeam = allEnemies.Where(enemy => enemy.team != team).ToArray();", -->"Where" has an error. Is there something I need to set?

Comment: Yes, you will need to create a script called "Enemy" and give it an enum called "team". Then add this script to all your enemies and make sure the value of "team" is correct!